# Array of objects filter issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs-filter

I have got the following JSON as an array and I am trying to filter on roles attribute but I am not able to filter the results. Please help me.

```
var data = [{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["CitySupervisor"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["clientsupervisor"]}];
```

The JavaScript code which I wrote is below:

```
var results = data.filter(function(user) {
  var roles = user.roles;

  return roles.filter(function(role) {
    return role == 'clientsupervisor';
  });
});
```

Comment: That is invalid JSON, you need to escape your double-quotes (`"`) or wrap your string in single-quotes (`'`). Note that JSON != JavaScript Object.

Comment: let's say i have two more keys at the same level of roles with names profileId and name. But in the result i need both of these keys name and profileId as id. How can we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` variable has a syntax error. You need to remove the quotes that are wrapping it.

Also a little change in your filtering code.

Change from this:

```
"[{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["CitySupervisor"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["clientsupervisor"]}]";
```

To this:

```
[{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["CitySupervisor"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["clientsupervisor"]}];
```

See it working:

```js
var data = [{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["CitySupervisor"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner"]},{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},{"roles":["partner","supervisor"]},{"roles":["clientsupervisor"], "name": "Jack", "profileId": 34533}];

var results = data.filter(function (user){
 return user.roles.indexOf('clientsupervisor') > -1;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: let's say i have two more keys at the same level of roles with names profileId and name. But in the result i need both of these keys name and profileId as id. How can we do it?

Comment: @Venkat, the same code works for more keys in the same level. I updated my example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

try this, simple way

```
var results = data.filter(function(user) {
    return user.roles.indexOf("clientsupervisor") > -1 ? true: false
});
```

and remove `""` from data object, this is array object

```
var data = [{"roles":["citysupervisor"]},.....];
```

Comment: let's say i have two more keys at the same level of roles with names profileId and name. But in the result i need both of these keys name and profileId as id. How can we do it?